# how to get out parameters from stored procedure via C Programming API

Tags: mysql

I've done some searches and scrutinized the C Programming API that is here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-prepared-statement-functions.html

Most of it geared towards fetching rows of data that come back, which is easy.  The sproc is being called like this from the C program (I know I should bind the parameters I will...) :

```
sprintf( cmd, "CALL get_graph_data( \"%s\", \"%s\");", symbol, scope );

if (mysql_query(conn, cmd)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
      exit(1);    
}

res = mysql_use_result(conn);
if( res == NULL ) { ;       // how do I get output parameters in this case ?  umm...
} else {                
   num_fields = mysql_num_fields(res);
   while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
   {   
        do stuff
   } 
}
```

the SPROC that I am calling looks like this :

```
create procedure get_graph_data (
    symbol varchar(20),
    period varchar(5),
    OUT status SMALLINT,
    OUT emsg varchar(255)
)
```

SO - I can't figure out the API calls to get at the two output parameters status and emsg.  also, in the case where the sproc produces zero rows (some validation of user input has to occur in the db without having to make extra calls to do that) then 'res' comes back NULL so not sure how to get at output parameters in that case ...

TIA !

Comment: consider using ' instead " around procedure parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try in this manner

first `CALL get_graph_data('xxx','yyy', @a, @b);`
and then `select @a, @b;`

**UPDT**
You can use simple interface instead of Prepared Statement API. But you should set enable [multiple-statement execution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html) to get values of `status` and `emsg`. Then "out of sync" error should disappear.

Comment: well, but then I have two results sets then to try and get.  meaning I would have to call 'mysql_use_result(cgi->conn)' two times somehow.  note sproc get_graph_data() already returns rows.  I have been trying to do this but am getting "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now".

Comment: heh I hit 'enter key' and this comment was slammed up before I was done.

Comment: wow I did it again!  ok, I'll continue to monkey around and if I get stuck repost a new question with where I am at.  Thx again for the responses!

Comment: ok - here's something.  The execution of the stored procedure produces a result set from that fact that '0 rows were affected'.  haha!  fool me once.  so I have to loop using mysql_next_result() whenever I call any stored procedure even if it produces one result set (ie : no OUT parameters).

Comment: Hi checking back in, does 'simple interface' exist as a C library?  I've seen some simple interface references to php (and I think perl).  thx for the help!  ps : I have solved my problem using mysql_next_result() as previously stated.